# Find the number of differences between two lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, comparison

I want to compare two lists with the same number of elements, and find the number of differences between them. Right now, I have this code (which works):

```
public static int CountDifferences<T> (this IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
{
    if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException ("Lists must have the same number of elements", "list2");

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals (list1[i], list2[i]))
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

This feels messy to me, and it seems like there must be a more elegant way to achieve it. Is there a way, perhaps, to combine the two lists into a single list of tuples, then simple examine each element of the new list to see if both elements are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since order in the list does count this would be my approach:

```
public static int CountDifferences<T>(this IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
{
    if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("Lists must have the same number of elements", "list2");

    int count  = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => a.Equals(b) ? 0 : 1).Sum();
    return count;
}
```

Simply merging the lists using [**`Enumerable.Zip()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) then summing up the differences, still O(n) but this just enumerates the lists once.

Also this approach would work on any two `IEnumerable` of the same type since we do not use the list indexer (besides obviously in your count comparison in the guard check).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2);
var differences = list1.Count - result.Count();
```

If order counts:

```
var result = a.Where((x,i) => x !=b[i]);
var differences = result.Count();
```

Comment: See my comment on Hawker's answer. For me, order matters.

Comment: Editted my response for case where order matters

Comment: Oh neat, I didn't know that `Enumerable.Where` had that overload. I'm going to go with `Enumerable.Zip` instead, but this works too!

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is fine, but you could use LINQ to simplify your function:

```
public static int CountDifferences<T>(this IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
{
    if(list1.Count != list2.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("Lists must have same # elements", "list2");
    return list1.Where((t, i) => !Equals(t, list2[i])).Count();
}
```

The way you have it written in the question, I don't think `Intersect` does what you're looking for.  For example, say you have:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
```

If you run `list1.CountDifferences(list2)`, I'm assuming that you want to get back 2 since elements 2 and 3 are different. `Intersect` in this case will return 5 since the lists have 5 elements in common. So, if you're looking for 5 then `Intersect` is the way to go. If you're looking to return 2 then you could use the LINQ statement above.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) extension method of Enumerable.

```
public static int CountDifferences<T> (this IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
{
    if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException ("Lists must have the same number of elements", "list2");

    return list1.Count - list1.Intersect(list2).Count();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `Intersect` provides the *set* intersection (ignoring order). In my case, order matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension method Zip of List.

```
List<int> lst1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> lst2 = new List<int> { 6, 2, 9, 4, 5 };
int cntDiff = lst1.Zip(lst2, (a, b) => a != b).Count(a => a);

// Output is 2
```